# Show Detail Component with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am learning react-router and trying to display a list of courses and course detail. But now, the CourseDetail2 component page does not display. Help!

App.js
    `
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import CourseList2 from './components/CourseList2'

```
//campus data
const campusData = [
{ id: 1, value:'A',name: 'A' },
{ id: 2, value:'B',name: 'B' },
{ id: 3, value:'C',name: 'C' }

]
class App extends Component {

state={campus:null,
   Courses:[]}
 componentDidMount(){
 //api call
setState={Courses:response.data}
}
//event handler
handleCampusChkChange()=>{
//code 
}
render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">


<Campus  key={item.id} {...item} onChange={this.handleCampusChkChange} />
<CourseList2 courses={this.state.Courses}/>

</div>


  );
  }
}

export default App;
`
```

CourseList2.js

```js
import React  from 'react';

import CourseDetail2 from './CourseDetail2';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import './CourseItem.css';
import App from './App';
const CourseList2=({Courses})=>{
    console.log("coruses="+Courses);
    const renderedList= Courses.map(course=>{
        return (<div className="item" >
     
    
        <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
        
        <h4>
             {course.SUBJECT} {course.CATALOG} {course.DESCR}  
             </h4> </div> 
      
        <Link  to={{ pathname: 'course/'+course.ID}}
                            
                            key={course.ID}>
                            View More
                        </Link>
        
       
    
          
        </div>
        </div> 
       
          
       
    )
    });
    return (
     
    <Router><div className="List ui relaxed divided list">

        {renderedList}
     
        <Route path="course/:course.ID" component={CourseDetail2} />
   
   </div></Router>);
}

export default CourseList2
```

CourseDetail2.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


   class CourseDetail2 extends Component {
    
    render(){
     
    return (
       <div>
        Course Detail: CLASS ID {this.props.match.params.ID}
      
    </div>
   
    );
    }   
};
export default CourseDetail2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as answer instead of comment.

Probably want to pass `this.state.Courses` to `CourseList2`, and wrap `CourseDetails2` with `withRouter` HOC from react-router-dom so it can access the route match prop.

Also, the path in the route in CourseList2 should probably be `path="course/:ID"` since that is how you access it on the details.

Comment: I edited code to pass this.state.Courses to CourseList2 and changed course.ID to ID and it works now. I have another question here, how to reset the URL and remove the ID? Using deleteparams?

Comment: Are you asking about seeing the whole path in the address bar? Well, the URL will be specific to that page, if you delete the the ID part it would be like navigating to "courses" and the details will likely unmount. Or do you just want to navigate back a page?

Comment: I want to reset URL to the original  home page.

Comment: I added a reset button with function onReset=()=>{
  
  this.setState({campus:null,
    Courses:[]});
  //remove class_nbr from url
  const params = new URLSearchParams(Location.search);
  params.delete('CLASS_NBR');
  
    this.props.history.push('/');

 } 
 but got error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Is `CourseList2` wrapped with `withRouter`? It won't have access to any route props like history of it isn't. And it would probably be sufficient to just `history go('/');`, there's no URL query parameters to clear anyway from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

`location, match and history` objects can only be accessed when you wrap the component with the higher order component `withRouter`.

Right now you don't have access to `this.props.match` in CourseDetail2 component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';


   class CourseDetail2 extends Component {

    render(){

    return (
       <div>
        Course Detail: CLASS ID {this.props.match.params.courseID}

    </div>

    );
    }   
};
export default withRouter(CourseDetail2);
```

Also the string after `:` doesn't have match with the code. It can be anything.

```
<Route path="course/:courseID" component={CourseDetail2} />
```

And you access using that string name in your code.